# How to decouple hatch and edge color in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw a bar in `matplotlib` with white as fill color, red as hatch color and black as edge color. However, it looks like the edge color changes also the color of hatch. So, I am not able to decouple the color of edges and hatch. Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Plot bar plot twice:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Polygon

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
# draw hatch
ax1.bar(range(1, 5), range(1, 5), color='none', edgecolor='red', hatch="/", lw=1., zorder = 0)
# draw edge
ax1.bar(range(1, 5), range(1, 5), color='none', edgecolor='k', zorder=1, lw=2.)

ax1.set_xticks([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you have suggestions also for the legend? I still get red hatch and red edges there

Comment: Add to legend black-edged patch.

Comment: It seems like this doesn't work with matplotlib version 2.0? When I run this code, I get a black hatch pattern.

Comment: @Coquelicot In Matplotlib 2.0 you can now configure the hatch colour directly with rcParams

Comment: This trick causes issues for stacked bar plots.

Answer (score 10):

In Matplotlib 2.0 you can now [configure the hatch colour directly](http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#hatching) with rcParams.

> The color and width of the lines in a hatch pattern are now configurable by the rcParams `hatch.color` and `hatch.linewidth`, with defaults of black and 1 point, respectively... There is no API level control of the hatch color or linewidth.
>
> Hatching patterns are now rendered at a consistent density, regardless of DPI. Formerly, high DPI figures would be more dense than the default, and low DPI figures would be less dense. This old behavior cannot be directly restored, but the density may be increased by repeating the hatch specifier.

Comment: that means I can only hatch in one color per plot... this is annoying...

Comment: seems to be in planing for 2.0.1 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7901

Comment: I have `matplotlib 3.1.1` and setting `plt.rcParams['hatch.color']` doesn't change anything for me. It works for linewidth though

Comment: For me, the `plt.rcParams['hatch.color']` did not work because another plot set the edge color. Apparently, this has higher precedence.

Comment: Another pitfall: Patch(color='red', hatch='/') will not make the hatch visible. Use Patch(facecolor='red', hatch='/') instead!