# How can I add different hatch colors in a matplotlib barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would like to change my hedge color based on the group my data belongs to. 
I found that I can change the color of the entire plot, and somehow [people seem to be able to do what I want](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7901/), but I really don't understand how to implement this in my bar plot. Ultimately, I want to have different mixes and matches of colored patches and colored hatches, but that's something I can figure out for myself.
This is an example stolen from another answer here on SO:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px

# Juwairia's data:     
a = [4,-6,9]
b = [2,-7,1]
c = [3,3,1]
d = [4,0,-3]
data = np.array([a, b, c, d])

data_shape = np.shape(data)

# Take negative and positive data apart and cumulate
def get_cumulated_array(data, **kwargs):
    cum = data.clip(**kwargs)
    cum = np.cumsum(cum, axis=0)
    d = np.zeros(np.shape(data))
    d[1:] = cum[:-1]
    return d  

cumulated_data = get_cumulated_array(data, min=0)
cumulated_data_neg = get_cumulated_array(data, max=0)

# Re-merge negative and positive data.
row_mask = (data<0)
cumulated_data[row_mask] = cumulated_data_neg[row_mask]
data_stack = cumulated_data

cols = [ i for i in px.colors.qualitative.Light24]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
bars=[]

for i in np.arange(0, data_shape[0]):
    bars.append(ax.bar(np.arange(data_shape[1]), data[i], bottom=data_stack[i], color=cols[i],))
bars[0][1].set_hatch('\\')# make this dark red - HOW?
bars[1][2].set_hatch('\\')#make this dark green - HOW?

plt.show()
```

Working with matplotlib 2.2.4 and Python 2.7
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168948/how-to-decouple-hatch-and-edge-color-in-matplotlib) the hatch color changes with the edge color. The answer then solves that by plotting twice: once for the hatch color and one for the edge color.

Comment: This is not a good solution as it messes up the labels and makes the legend inconsistent. :(